# How to keep SQL Queries in seperate sql files in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Currently sql queries are assigned to String variables and variable is used in JDBCTemplates. I want to know how to keep these queries separately ( in .sql files) and use them in JDBC. (I don't use any ORM framework here. I use MySql and Postresql)

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic Java classes to read a text file, which is available in your classpath:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyQuery.sql");
```

But you should reflect, wether it's a good idea to keep that separated from your code and if you shouldn't use [Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead. You surely have parameters in your SQL queries and you should always let the framework substitude them, as well for robustness as for security reasons.